# Android Intel device will only run armeabi or x86 .so libraries, but not a mixture of both?

Tags: android, android-ndk, x86, java-native-interface

I have two .so libraries in my APK:

1) LibraryA: Builds only for ARM architectures because I don't want to port all of the code to x86.  It's a massive undertaking.

2) LibraryB: Builds for ARM and x86.  The ARM libhoudini emulator is too slow for Intel devices to run this library at a decent speed, so it must have an x86 port which is working fine.

The lib folders in the APK look like this:

../lib/armeabi/LibraryA
../lib/armeabi/LibraryB

../lib/x86/LibraryB  (Note: x86 does not have LibraryA)

When I install/run the APK on an Intel device, it defaults to the ARM architecture for the .so libraries and ignores the x86 version of LibraryB.  The result being, it's emulated and too slow for production.  Everything works great on an ARM device though, no problem there.

How do I force Android to work correctly on an Intel device so it emulates the ARM version of LibraryA and runs the x86 version of LibaryB?

For sake of completeness, I'm using android-ndk-r10d to build.

Answer (score 0):

I can trick Android to load the x86 version of LibraryB by putting the ARM compiled version of LibraryA in the "../lib/x86" folder.  Even though LibraryA is compiled for ARM, it will still load up and then Android will also load the x86 version of LibraryB.

../lib/armeabi/LibraryA
../lib/armeabi/LibraryB

../lib/x86/LibraryA (compiled for ARM, but still works)
../lib/x86/LibraryB (compiled for x86)

Answer (score 0):

Mixed arm/x86 applications are not supported. The behavior in your workaround is not guaranteed, and both behaviors you're seeing may actually vary across devices and OS versions.

The only solution here is porting library A to x86.